# How to extract the information of Total Confirmed from webpage with selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After clicking the selected country I want to get the number of "Total Confirmed" from the top of the website

Website:
https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6

Below is the code i have written:

```
poland = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h5//span[contains(text(),'Poland')]")
poland.click()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the number "1,862" clicking on *Poland* is not mandatory, instead you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for either `visibility_of_element_located()` or `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH* and ``:

  ```
  driver.get('https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h5//span[contains(text(),'Poland')]//preceding::span[2]/strong"))).text)
  ```

  - Console Output:

    ```
    1,862
    ```
- Using *XPATH* and ``:

  ```
  driver.get('https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h5//span[contains(text(),'Poland')]//preceding::span[2]/strong"))).text)
  ```

  - Console Output:

    ```
    1,862
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```